# My javascript function is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I was working on a website project.
I saw an animation for images in w3schools.
I've tried it and it works perfectly well for just one picture--

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
var img = document.getElementById('a');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");


img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

but i wanna use this for multiple images.
So i created a function like that:

```js
function myBeautifulFunc(imageId, modalImageId) {

  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  var img = document.getElementById(imageId);
  var modalImg = document.getElementById(modalImageId);
  

  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  }

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

and called this function:
`myBeautifulFunc('a', 'img01')`

the result is:
it worked for the first image but when i tried it on second,
it looked like this: https://ibb.co/Mk8Xw1Z

I wanna show only one image when i clicked on it,
but it shows both of the images.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What is `imageId`?

Comment: can you show us some more code? and also format it a bit better

Comment: @Nathan Sorry, first time asking a question here i edited the code now

Comment: @HerbieVine edited

Comment: Thanks! Do you dynamically call this function, or is it just called to test? Can you show us?

Comment: From the looks of your code, the children nodes img and modalImg are not being hidden. So the second time you click it, your seeing the one from before. In your close function hide the img and modalImg also

Comment: Hmm, don't see why this question was voted down, its obvious from look at the code what the problem is, and this guy has obviously tried his best to figure it out and provide as much information as possible

Comment: It's not actually modal you need. A light box.https://codepen.io/nowayblack/pen/xxZYzEq

Comment: @MaxCarroll thank you,      modalImg.style.display = "none";       when i add this code it solved my problem. but i deleted this one img.style.display = "none";  bc it didnt show the image on website after closing the big image version. but again, thank you very much for help.

Comment: Awesome stuff @merve , when you have enough reputation points can you accept and vote up my answer if you found it useful 

Comment: ofcourse! @MaxCarroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your close function `span.onclick = function()` is not hiding the children, so the second time you click, you are seeing the previous image and modalImage from the last time it was clicked.

```
function myBeautifulFunc(imageId, modalImageId) {

  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  var img = document.getElementById(imageId);
  var modalImg = document.getElementById(modalImageId);
  

  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  }

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    img.style.display = "none"         // hide this also
    modalImg.style.display = "none"     // hide this also
  }
}
```

### Before Any clicks

- .myModal = hidden
- img1 = hidden
- modalImg1 = hidden

### After Clicking the first time and then closing

- .myModal = hidden
- img1 = visible
- modalImg1 = visible

### After clicking the second time

- .myModal = hidden
- img1 = visible
- modalImg1 = visible
- img2 = visible
- modalImg2 = visible